# how to calculate dissimilarity in R without using function?

Tags: r

I have the data as following:

```
class atrribute1 attribute2 attribute3
1     21362      97         437
1     312312     3123       341
2     97987      7227       112
3     8398       333        333
```

I tried to do the dissimilarity calculation of `class` based on trribute1,2,3. and assume to output a 3x3 dissimilarity matrix.

I checked online there is lots of function,but no one is dealing with this kind of data. Is there anyone can help?

Comment: How are the first two rows different?

Comment: @jlhoward maybe I mislead you. Class is also an attibute, but it only can be 1, 2 or 3

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If you have attributes 1-3 + class, that's **4** variables, so the distance matrix will be 4 X 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute average attribute values across all observations from each class and then compute pairwise distances between classes:

```
# Just to see the aggregated data
aggregate(.~class, data=dat, mean)
#   class atrribute1 attribute2 attribute3
# 1     1     166837       1610        389
# 2     2      97987       7227        112
# 3     3       8398        333        333

# Compute pairwise distances
dist(aggregate(.~class, data=dat, mean)[2:4], diag=T, upper=T)
#           1         2         3
# 1      0.00  69079.30 158444.16
# 2  69079.30      0.00  89854.13
# 3 158444.16  89854.13      0.00
```